# Jquery looping results

Tags: jquery, html, loops, append

I'm trying to loop all matched results so they appear in a list form. I have tried using **$('div#comments').html(commentdata);** - but it only shows me the first match of data / the first comment.

I then tried using **.append** instead of **.html**, this shows all the comments ok - but adds all the data on again everytime I run the onClick event that is attached to the request.

*In short; how can I list all of my comments, without them being added/appended every time I click on the object that loads them.*

---

```
var xml = data.responseXML;

var comments = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("comment");

for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {

      var user = comments[i].getAttribute("username");
      var comm = comments[i].getAttribute("comment");
      var commentdata = "<li>"+ user +" - " + comm +"</li>";

      $('div#comments').append(commentdata);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xml = data.responseXML;

var comments = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("comment");

// html collection
var commentdata = [];

// open <ul>
commentdata.push('<ul>');

// cache this
var len = comments.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

      var user = comments[i].getAttribute("username");
      var comm = comments[i].getAttribute("comment");

      // add <li> element
      commentdata.push("<li>"+ user +" - " + comm +"</li>");

}

// end <ul>
commentdata.push('</ul>');

// update <div id="comments"> contents
$('div#comments').html(commentdata.join("\n"));
```

Praveen is also correct, you could just empty the container before you start appending data:

```
$('div#comments').empty();
```

Comment: This demonstrates a good practice of only manipulating the DOM once per click, not once per comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var xml = data.responseXML;

    var comments = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("comment");

// clear previous data here
    $('div#comments').empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {

          var user = comments[i].getAttribute("username");
          var comm = comments[i].getAttribute("comment");
          var commentdata = "<li>"+ user +" - " + comm +"</li>";

          $('div#comments').append(commentdata);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event-attachment method. So e.g.

```
$("#id-of-thing-to-click").one("click", function () {
    // the code from your post
});
```

The click event will then only be triggered the first time someone clicks on `#id-of-thing-to-click`, instead of every time.

Comment: You are correct ( mis understood the question). I am deleting my answer.